# Design tab title CSS to connect with tab content - circle corners

Tags: html, css, psd

I'm trying to design html + css tabs to look like this design:
When tab is selected, the title is connected to the tab content and the "neck" rounds in like arrow shows.

[image: corner connection tab should be circle like border radius Xpx]
[image: Round corners in]
I managed to get here so far like this a image attached with a div that connects the title and content tab. The problem is the corner is not round.
I can't do border radius because its not really one div, it's 2 divs connected. 
I'm sure they a better way to achieve this look. 
How could a get the design done in html? 
[image]

Comment: Is there any way you can show the current HTML or perhaps psuedo code it out? I am not understanding why we can't just solve with more divs :)

Comment: The problem is how i make the part that with arrows in image 2 round.

Comment: Please see update.

Answer (score -2):

One possible solution would be to surround all of the other tabs in some form of a `div` and then use the [CSS `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius` properties](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp)

```
<!-- Psuedocode idea, have not tested... -->
<div id=#tabwrapperLeft style="border-radius-bottom-right: 5px">
  <div>tab1</div>
  <div>tab2</div>
  ...
  <div>tabI-1</div>
</div>

<div>tabI</div>

<div id=#tabwrapperRight style="border-radius-bottom-left: 5px">
  <div>tabI+1</div>
  ...
  <div>tabN</div>
</div>
```

In your example above, the blue, orange and yellow tabs, surrounded in an element styled with border-bottom-right radius. However, in a more general case, such as if the yellow tab was selected, unselected tabs to the right would need border-bottom-left-radius.

Let me know what you think!

Comment: I think i  did like you wrote. The problem is that the coroners "round" outside of the div. I added another image

Comment: For my own sake, anyone mind giving some explanation for the downvotes? Did I misunderstand the question, or is this not a desirable implementation?